# ChartJS - Help me custom tooltip

Tags: chart.js

The first image is default tooltip. I want to produce the second image:

[image: My desired tooltip]
.

This is the default options:

```
tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label %>: <%}%><%= value %>",
multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>"
```

When I change the second option (multiTooltipTemplate) same as first option, I got this:

[image]
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **datasetLabel** key to access curves label. Still it wont change text color.

```
multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel + ' ' + value %>"
```